How to get the login screen to use screen mirroring in macOS 14?
I have an M1 Mac Mini running macOS 14.4.1 that is partially headless. It's always connected to a headless HDMI dummy plug, and occasionally I connected a portable Thunderbolt screen to it. I always leave the dummy plug connected so that, when screen sharing, I can change the resolution to whatever I want.
When logged in, I have the screens set to mirror so that the display associated with the dummy plug doesn't get its own desktop that I can't see.
However, ever since I upgraded from macOS 13 to 14, now on the login screen the screens are not mirrored, and the dummy plug is considered the primary screen. Consequently, I cannot see anything with the portable screen connected making it very difficult to log in!
I can't find any way to control the display arrangement on the login screen. It doesn't use any of the arrangements configured for any of my user accounts. How can I change it so that it uses display mirroring?

When I use screen sharing to access a Mac with two screens, I am able to select which screen to view or select both screens. An example is shown below.


Yes, when connecting to the headless mac with screen sharing I can see the correct screen when at the login screen. However, this question is about when I'm physically at the computer and the portable thunderbolt display is connected.
